# A select query selecting a select statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, ms-access-2007

I don't even know if I am doing this query the right way.
There is a `Sandwiches` table that has some 7 fields and 2 of them are comboboxes (`Type` and `Bread`).

So I made a query that combines all of the comboboxes values into one query, like this:

```
SELECT TypesAndBreads.TBName, TypesAndBreads.Type
FROM (SELECT [Sandwiches Types].[Sandwich Type] As TBName, "Sandwich Type" As Type
    FROM [Sandwiches Types]
UNION ALL
    SELECT Breads.Bread As TBName, "Bread" As Type 
    FROM Breads)  AS TypesAndBreads;
```

I get the flat values of the tables now I want to count all the sandwiches under each `TypesAndBreads.TBName`. I have this, just to make sure it works with all the Sandwiches:

```
SELECT TypesAndBread.Type, TypesAndBread.TBName,
       (SELECT Count(Sandwiches.[SandwichID]) As SandwichCount
        FROM Sandwiches) As SandwichCount
FROM TypesAndBread;
```

But I want to reference the current Type and TBName inside the subquery. Something like this:

```
SELECT TypesAndBread.Type, TypesAndBread.TBName,
       (SELECT Count(Sandwiches.[SandwichID]) As SandwichCount
        FROM Sandwiches
        WHERE Sandwiches.[TypesAndBread.Type] = Sandwiches.[TypesAndBread.TBName]) As SandwichCount
FROM TypesAndBread;
```

But of course this doesn't work. I didn't think it will, just thought of giving it a try. I was thinking of maybe constructing the query with VBA when they open the Report that this query is going to be based of.

**So I guess my question is:** Is there a way to reference the current selected fields in a subquery? Or is there a different way to approach this?

Thanks for the help

**EDIT:**
My table structure is like this:

`Sandwiches`'s fields

```
| SandwichID | Name | Date Added | Chef | Sandwich Type | Bread | Reviewed By |
```

where `Sandwich Type` and `Bread` are Lookup fields for these tables:

`Sandwiches Types`'s fields

```
| Sandwich Type |
```

`Breads`'s fields

```
| Bread |
```

The TypesAndBreads query combined the Sandwiches Types and Breads tables, but the reason for that is so that I can get the count of all the sandwiches that have that Type or bread. A result like this:

```
+=============================================+
|      Type     |    TBName   | SandwichCount |
+=============================================+
| Sandwich Type | Turkey Club |            10 |
| Bread         | Italian     |             5 |
| Bread         | Garlic      |             8 |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

the example result's first row basicly says there are 10 sandwiches in record with the Sandwich Type field equal to Turkey Club.

I hope that explains it better.

Comment: I am finding this a bit confusing. Can you post your table structure and the desired output?

Comment: I added the table structure and some desired output, hope that helps. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Not sure if Access supports it, but in most engines (including `SQL Server`) this is called a correlated subquery and works fine:

```
SELECT  TypesAndBread.Type, TypesAndBread.TBName,
        (
        SELECT  Count(Sandwiches.[SandwichID]) As SandwichCount
        FROM    Sandwiches
        WHERE   (Type = 'Sandwich Type' AND Sandwiches.Type = TypesAndBread.TBName)
                OR (Type = 'Bread' AND Sandwiches.Bread = TypesAndBread.TBName)
        ) As SandwichCount
FROM    TypesAndBread
```

This can be made more efficient by indexing `Type` and `Bread` and distributing the subqueries over the `UNION`:

```
SELECT  [Sandwiches Types].[Sandwich Type] As TBName, "Sandwich Type" As Type,
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*) As SandwichCount
        FROM    Sandwiches
        WHERE   Sandwiches.Type = [Sandwiches Types].[Sandwich Type]
        )
FROM    [Sandwiches Types]
UNION ALL
SELECT  [Breads].[Bread] As TBName, "Bread" As Type,
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*) As SandwichCount
        FROM    Sandwiches
        WHERE   Sandwiches.Bread = [Breads].[Bread]
        )
FROM    [Breads]
```

Comment: Jet/ACE has always supported correlated subqueries. However, they are often not well-optimized in terms of index usage.

Answer (score 7):

I was over-complicating myself. After taking a long break and coming back, the desired output could be accomplished by this simple query:

```
SELECT Sandwiches.[Sandwich Type], Sandwich.Bread, Count(Sandwiches.[SandwichID]) AS [Total Sandwiches]
FROM Sandwiches
GROUP BY Sandwiches.[Sandwiches Type], Sandwiches.Bread;
```

Thanks for answering, it helped my train of thought.