# SQL join or PHP loop? or what?

Tags: php, mysql

So i have two queries to give me the information i need and im trying to figure out the best way to get the result from them. i have a table of Holdings. using:

```
SELECT symbol, sum(shares) AS shares, sum(shares * price) AS cost 
FROM Transactions 
WHERE (action <>5) 
    AND date <= '2010-10-30' 
GROUP BY symbol HAVING sum(shares) > 0
```

which results in

```
AGNC    50.00     1390.0000
RSO     1517.00   9981.8600
T       265.00    6668.7500
```

I then have another query

```
SELECT close FROM History WHERE symbol = $symbol AND date = $date
```

which will return the closing price of that day.

```
T    24.40
```

i want to basically for a given date calculate value so sum(shares * close) for each symbol. but i dont know how to do that with out looping through each row in php. i was hoping there was a join or something i could do in sql to make the data return the way i want it

Comment: FYI you can use a number to compare a date value `date`<=20101030 but date is a reserved word, it shouldn't be a column name.

Comment: @popnoodles - but as so many people use date as a column name, it's one of the few reserved words that doesn't actually need backticks

Comment: Is that true Mark or are you pulling my leg?

Comment: im using it without backticks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could do something similar to this: [A select query selecting a select statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043845/a-select-query-selecting-a-select-statement)  Put your second query literally in your first query. Not sure about exact syntax, but like:

```
SELECT 
    symbol, 
    sum(shares) AS shares, 
    sum(shares * price) AS cost, 
    sum(shares * close) as value 
FROM Transactions 
INNER JOIN History ON (symbol = $symbol AND date = $date)
WHERE (action <>5) 
    AND date <= '2010-10-30' 
GROUP BY symbol HAVING sum(shares) > 0
```

@popnoodles is right about your naming though. If you use date I'd think you'd need [date].

Comment: The problem with using another select query in there is that it only gives me that one symbol. As you can see in the first query example i have more than one symbol. i was hoping there might be a join of some sort i could do. other wise ill just have to do a loop in php

Comment: Well, I think you could do something like `INNER JOIN History ON (symbol = $symbol AND date = $date)` and then add close to your select list and use it there. I think that will work. I am not sure if you can do that but I think you can.

Comment: `INNER JOIN History ON (History.symbol = Transactions.symbol AND History.date = Transactions.date)`?

Comment: THis is the way i got the data i wanted  `SELECT 
    Transactions.symbol, 
    sum(shares) AS shares, 
    sum(shares * price) AS cost,
    History.close as close,
    (shares * History.close) as value 
FROM Transactions 
INNER JOIN History ON (History.symbol = Transactions.symbol AND History.date ='2013-02-08') 
WHERE (action <>5) AND Transactions.date <= '2013-02-08' 
GROUP BY Transactions.symbol HAVING sum(shares) > 0`