# Get 1 row from multiple columns

Tags: sql-server-2012, pivot

I have 2 tables

table#1:  Order

```
orderid  unitid  active
      1      aa      1      
      2      bb      0
      3      cc      1
      4      dd      1
```

table#2:Details

```
orderid     month
      1         6
      1         7
      1        12
      2         1
      2         6
      3         1
      3         2
      3         3
      3         4
      3         6
```

Output desired:

```
orderid   unitid     jan   feb  mar  apr  may  jun  .........  dec
  1           aa                               yes             yes
  3           cc     yes   yes  yes  yes
```

For all orders where ACTIVE is 1 and all unitids.

I tried using case statement, i get multiple rows for a single orderid, which is not how i want.

I see a lot of examples for pivot with one table, how to do this using 2 tables? I am using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Hi, does "SQL 2012" mean SQL Server 2012? Why then is it tagged Oracle? If not what does it mean? It'd be great if you could also [edit] your question to include what you've tried so far. Thanks!

Comment: To do it with two tables, just write a join and pivot the results.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a Select within a SELECT as argument

Something like this;

```
Select orderid, unitid, (SELECT month 
                         From Table2 
                         WHERE ...)
From table1
Where ...
```

I am referencing with this answer this Issue:

[A select query selecting a select statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043845/a-select-query-selecting-a-select-statement)